# What is the from uri= when you are defining the Camel route in xml?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have several services that I would like to add Camel routes.  The examples in xml I see are like so:

```
<route id="myId"
from uri="direct:inside"/>
to uri="mock:inside"/>
</route>
```

Where can I find the acceptable values for the string after "from uri="?

Also if I'm in ServiceA that seems like what I should put in the from uri.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can you point us to an example?  This example is not a valid XML document for many reasons.  "from uri" is not a valid XML attribute name, and even though "from" is, all attribute names must be followed by `=` and a quoted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Camel components have documentation which options they support. For example the direct component, has only 1 option listed
http://camel.apache.org/direct

You can see a list of all the components here:
http://camel.apache.org/components

Comment: So the excepted values are the components.

Comment: Yes. Technically its an endpoint uri, where the first part of the uri, is the component name (the scheme part of the uri).